# Can't show the name from binded/relationship model in asp.core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

following my previous question ([asp.net core creating/updating a foreignkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123037/asp-net-core-creating-updating-a-foreignkey)), I want to display the name of the pharmacy from my Todo model. The following code are actually used:

```
public class Todo
    {
        public Pharmacy Pharmacy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pharmacy
        {
            [Key]
            public int PharmacyID { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

the connector for my selectbox into my create/edit form:

```
public class PharmacynamePageModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public int SelectedPharmacy { get; set; }

        public SelectList PharmacyNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulatePharmacysDropDownList(ApplicationDbContext _context, object selectedPharmacy = null)
        {
            var query = (from p in _context.Pharmacy orderby p.Name select p).ToList();

            PharmacyNameSL = new SelectList(query, "PharmacyID", "Name", selectedPharmacy);
        }
    }
```

and into my  list (index.cshtml):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Todo)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OwnerID)
                </td>
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pharmacy.Name)
            </td>
       }
```

I tried without succes the following variant:

- item.Pharmacy
- item.Pharmacy.PharmacyID (but i want print the name)

I controlled with SQLServer Management Studio, and My column "PharmacyID" contains value after creating or editing data.

Hope you can help me ;)

Thanks per advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) allows you to use the navigation properties in your model to load related entities. Check if you use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results like the sample below

```
 public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Todo = await _context.Todo
                              .Include(t => t.Pharmacy).ToListAsync();
    }
```